# Error when sending sending HTTP/2 request using existing TLS socket

Tags: node.js, http2

I wrote a script to establish a TCP connection to target website, wrap it with TLS connection and then use that TLS connection to open HTTP/2 session. It works  normal for all website, but when I do HTTP/2 request to m.twitch.tv, the script show this error:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:717:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1595:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: undefined,
  host: undefined,
  port: undefined,
  localAddress: undefined
}
```

This is my script:

```js
// Usage: node file.js m.twitch.tv 443
const net = require("net");
const tls = require("tls");
const http2 = require("http2");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const host = process.argv[2];
const port = ~~process.argv[3];
const headers = {};
headers[":authority"] = host;
headers[":method"] = "GET";
headers[":path"] = "/";
headers[":scheme"] = "https";
headers["accept"] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7";
headers["accept-language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.9";
headers["dnt"] = "1";
headers["sec-ch-ua"] = '"Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"';
headers["sec-ch-ua-mobile"] = "?0";
headers["sec-ch-ua-platform"] = '"Windows"';
headers["sec-fetch-dest"] = "document";
headers["sec-fetch-mode"] = "navigate";
headers["sec-fetch-site"] = "none";
headers["sec-fetch-user"] = "?1";
headers["upgrade-insecure-requests"] = "1";
headers["user-agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.7.7895.91 Safari/537.36";
const socket = net.connect(port, host);
const tlsOptions = {
    ALPNProtocols: ["h2"],
    servername: host,
    socket: socket,
};
const tlsConn = tls.connect(tlsOptions);
tlsConn.on("secureConnect", () => {
    const client = http2.connect("https://" + host, {
        createConnection: () => tlsConn
    });
    client.on("connect", () => {
        let responseCode = 0;
        const request = client.request(headers);
        request.on("response", response => {
            responseCode = response[":status"];
        });
        request.on("data", data => {
            console.log(data.toString(), "\nResponse status: " + responseCode);
            client.close();
        });
    });
})
```

**With [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) it works fine.**

```
$ node file.js www.google.com 443
...
events:none;position:fixed;right:0;top:-80px;transition:opacity 0.218s,box-shadow 0.218s}.s2wfp .permission-bar-gradient{box-shadow:0 1px 80px #4285f4;opacity:1;pointer-events:none;animation:allow-alert .75s 0 infinite;animation-direction:alternate;animation-timing-function:ease-out;transition:opacity 0.218s,box-shadow 0.218s}@-webkit-keyframes allow-alert {from{opacity:1}to{opacity:.35}}\x3c/style\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22permission-bar-gradient\x22\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/div\x3e');})();(function(){google.drty&&google.drty(undefined,true);})();});google.drty&&google.drty(undefined,true);</script></body></html>
Response status: 200
```

**But with m.twitch.tv, the program exited with this error.**

```
$ node file.js m.twitch.tv 443
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:717:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1595:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: undefined,
  host: undefined,
  port: undefined,
  localAddress: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twitch.tv, as of writing, does not support HTTP2. You can check with cURL:

```
curl -v -o /dev/null --http2 https://m.twitch.tv
```

Note how in the output after negotiation(*) you get a HTTP1.1 response.

Twitch does support HTTP3 but this protocol very different from HTTP2. It's possible for servers to support HTTP1, 2 and 3, but they've chosen not to. It's likely that their target audience is all using modern browsers and that it's fine for them to support just 1 and 3.

---

(*) You'll get the following output if you run the command:

```
# curl indicates that it understands these two protocols:
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
...
# The server picks from this list:
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
...
# Response:
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

As opposed to the following (this example uses google.com):

```
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
...
* ALPN: server accepted h2
...
< HTTP/2 200
```